# "if A, B" and "B, if A" have difference nuance?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Several years ago, I heard that "if A, B" and "B, if A" have difference nuance from Radio English. but not sure I understood correctly and even if understood correctly I can't remember what's the diffrence.

For example, I've written 3 expressions. Which is correct? Are both correct? (if then, which is used commonly in English)

1. *"You get an error if you click this button"* v.s *"If you click this button, you gen an error"*
2. *"You can download mp3 files if you subscribe"* v.s *"If you subscribe, You can download mp3 files"*
3. *"I'll be there if you come"* v.s *"If you come, I'll be there"*

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these six examples are perfectly correct and used regularly!

The difference is in the emphasis.

I tend to find the `if A, B` statements are used to entice and convince (or to scare off if used with negative statements: `If you're bad, you can't have a cookie`) This can show a stronger sense of cause and effect.

Whereas the `B, if A` tend to be used to state simple facts. You still get a sense of cause and effect but it's less because they are in the wrong order.